# FreeImage API pagination

Tags: php, android, api, pagination

I am using [FreeImage API](http://[http://freeimages.pictures/api/user/1234567812345678/?keyword=sunny%20beach&format=json). In this how to get pagination of this API after completion of 16 response.

When i search in the FreeImage site, there is a button called "more images" and it loads another 16 images. But I couldn't get that through the API.

I embed by adding `&page=1` or `2` etc., but still same response. They don't provide pagination, or I am missing something?

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Pagination is not supported. 
But there is another bad way.

http://freeimages.pictures/ajax/view_more/flickr/?q=sunny%20beach&page=1
http://freeimages.pictures/ajax/view_more/flickr/?q=sunny%20beach&page=2